# iOS Swift + Alamofire upload photos with exif data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, exif

I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to upload multiple files at the same time to [Open Asset](https://openasset.com) using [their REST API](http://help.openasset.com/06_Integration/REST_API/Files) and I am able to get this to work, however, most of the EXIF data is being stripped out. Unfortunately, the EXIF data is a must as we need the ability mine out the GPS tags and a few other things through various web clients.

After doing some research, I found the issue is because I'm using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert the photos to `NSData` (which is what `Alamofire` expects or a fileURL, which I don't think would work for me?).

I am also using the [BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker) library to allow the user to take/select multiple photos, which returns a an array of [PHAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/)s which then get converted to `NSData`.  Here is my function to do this (where `collectedImages` is a global dictionary):

```
func compressPhotos(assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void {
        for asset in assets {
            let filename = self.getOriginalFilename(asset)
            let assetImage = self.getAssetPhoto(asset)

            let compressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(assetImage, 0.5)!  // bye bye metadata :(
            collectedImages[filename] = compressedImage
            print("compressed image: \(filename)")
        }
    }
```

I think I could retain the EXIF data if I could use the full path from the `PHAsset` to the image locally on the phone, but `Alamofire` does not appear to support that.  I'm hoping I'm wrong about that.  Here is my uploader:

```
func uploadPhotos(projectId: String, categoryId: String, data: [String: NSData], completionHandler: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()) {
        var jsonBody = [AnyObject]()  //lazy
        Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            self.url + "/Files",
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                for (filename, img) in data {
                    jsonBody.append(["project_id": projectId, "category_id": categoryId, "original_filename": filename])
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: img, name: "file", fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    print("img size: \(img.length)")

                }
                let jsonData = jsonToNSData(jsonBody)
                print("_jsonBody: \(jsonBody)")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: jsonData!, name: "_jsonBody")
                print("multipart: \(multipartFormData)")
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                        switch response.result {
                        case .Success(let value):
                            completionHandler(value as? NSArray, nil)
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            completionHandler(nil, error)
                        }

                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

So my question is, how can I upload multiple photos (while passing in other parameters too) while maintaining all the EXIF data?  `Alamofire` is an awesome library and I would like to use it here, but I'm not married to it for the upload process if I can't keep the EXIF data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why I was having issues with the `fullSizeImageURL`, but I it did lead me to the right path as I was able to get this to work by getting the image as `NSData` from the file path like this:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (input, _) in
    let fileURL = input!.fullSizeImageURL?.filePathURL
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileURL!.path!)!
```

And then I just passed that in the `Alamofire.request()` as the `data` argument.  This maintained all the original photo metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first get the file URL from the PHAsset then use that file URL in the call to  multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(...). Something like this:

1. Get URL from PHAsset:

   ```
   [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions
                          completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
   NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
   }];
   ```
2. Use file URL in AlamoFire API:

   `multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imageURL, name: "image")`

Comment: Ahh, that sounded promising, but it didn't work...Now I get an error `file URL is not reachable: file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2469.JPG"`.  Not sure why it wouldn't be reachable?  I just checked the [source code](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/MultipartFormData.swift) (line 255) and it seems like this is checking for the OS X 10.10 operating system or something?  I don't really know what is going on there.